# What is the longest an NFL team has gone without a WR TD catch?

Tags: trivia, nfl

The Kansas City Chiefs have not had a wide receiver catch a touchdown pass so far this season (through Week 15).  According to [team stats](http://www.nfl.com/teams/statistics?team=kc), only running backs, fullbacks, and tight ends have caught a TD pass so far this season.

According to the [NFL_Stats twitter account](https://twitter.com/NFL_Stats/status/546739886670483456), the Chiefs haven't had a WR catch a TD pass since December 8, 2013:

> The #Chiefs have not had a WR catch a TD pass since December 8th, 2013

That is 17 straight regular season games without a WR catching a TD pass (the Chiefs did have a WR catch a TD pass in their playoff game last season).  A [December 19 article](http://www.steelers.com/news/countdown-to-kickoff/article-1/Countdown-Steelers-vs-Chiefs/cca59ceb-f5d0-4a6e-bdd9-e146a460e0b4) on Steelers.com confirms this:

> A Chiefs wide receiver hasn’t caught a touchdown pass in 17 straight games, since Dwayne Bowe on Dec. 8, 2013 at Washington.

Has an NFL team ever gone an entire season without a wide receiver catching a touchdown pass?

What is the longest streak of games an NFL team has gone without a wide receiver catching a touchdown pass?

Answer (score 3):

"Has an NFL team ever gone an entire season without a wide receiver catching a touchdown pass?"

Yes, according to the [Sporting News](http://www.sportingnews.com/nfl/story/2014-12-28/kansas-city-chiefs-wide-receivers-touchdowns-catches-stats-numbers-alex-smith-season-andy-reid-dwayne-bowe-draft-pick), three teams from before the NFL's modern era did that:

> only three teams have gone through a season without a wide receiver catching a touchdown, and all of them played in a bygone era. The last team to do it was the Giants in 1964, when the Bears had the NFL's best passing offense at just over 200 yards per game.

Another [article](http://www.columbiamissourian.com/a/183160/chiefs-still-without-touchdown-catch-from-wide-receiver/) mentions the two teams besides the 1964 Giants who did that:

> Delving further into history yields other teams, including 1960 Washington and 1950 Pittsburgh, who didn't have a "wide receiver" catch a TD pass.

That article also says that before 2014, no team had ever had fewer than 2 touchdown catches by a wide receiver in a 16 game season:

> The fewest touchdown catches by a group of wide receivers in a 16-game season is two, set by the 1981 Saints and matched by the 2004 Giants.

But then in 2014, the Kansas City Chiefs went the entire season without a wide receiver catching a touchdown pass (from the Sporting News article):

> Alex Smith hit wide receiver Dwayne Bowe for a 22-yard touchdown in the first quarter of a 45-10 win over the Redskins on Dec. 8, 2013. 385 days and 19 games later, we're still waiting to put "Chiefs wide receiver" and "touchdown" in the same sentence. [...] The Chiefs, eliminated from playoff contention after a Ravens win, officially finished an entire season without a WR catching a touchdown pass.

The Chiefs finally ended the streak at 21 regular season games when WR Jeremy Maclin caught a TD pass in Week 3 of the 2015 season.